# How to evaluate this integral $\int_0^∞ ax^me^{-{ax}^n} dx$

Tags: definite-integrals, gamma-function

Trying to solve it using the gamma function

$ax^me^{-u} = u \times (\frac{u^{\frac{1}{n}}}{a^{\frac{1}{n}}})^{m – n-n +1}$

I actually used the fact that

$ax^n \times ax^{m-n} = ax^m$

so $u = ax^n$

$dx = \frac{du}{nax^{n-1}}$

So that's how $-n+1$ comes in

I take $a^{\frac{-m}{n} +1 - \frac{1}{n}}$ out of the integral

Note : I multiplied -1 to the power because i were to move the **inverse** of it outside the integral

I am left with 
$n^{-1} a^{\frac{-m}{n} +1 - \frac{1}{n}}\int_0^∞ u^{\frac{m}{n} -1 + \frac{1}{n}} e^{-u}du$

So I actually I need the gamma function for $\frac{m}{n} + \frac{1}{n}$ and multiply it with the constants ?

Comment: Any conditions on $m$ and $n$? Also, I doubt the integral converges unless $a \le 0$.

Comment: Please replace `e^{{ax}^n}` by `e^{-(ax)^n}` and add `dx` in the title.

Comment: Right, now we have a problem... completely solved in the post. So, what is the question exactly?

Comment: Your basic idea seems to be correct, but you've presented it here in the form of somewhat cryptic scratch work.  (For example, an experienced eye can interpret what you've set out to do in the first displayed equation, but the equation itself is wrong. As currently written, it's tantamount to saying $e^{-ax^n}=x^{1-n}$.). If you edit the question to more clearly describe the steps you're taking, someone may be able to give a helpful answer.

Comment: @BarryCipra I wanted to do this

Comment: $ax^{n} * ax^{m-n} = ax^{m}$

Comment: Anyways the question is more clarified now .Thanks :)